# python: matplotlib output file name

Tags: python, matplotlib, filenames

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *

filename = sys.argv[1]
num_, bin_, count_, err_ = loadtxt(filename, unpack=True)

plt.step(bin_,count_, where='mid', color='red')
plt.yscale('log')

plt.savefig(filename+'.pdf')
plt.show()
```

inside the above code, I want to save the output plot as the same name to the filename (== sys.argv[1]).

The following not working.

```
plt.savefig(filename+'.pdf')
```

Can anyone please suggest the appropriate one?

Comment: That's probably because the filename already contains ".pdf". So you're now storing it as "<filename>.pdf.pdf". Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

From https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html:

> If format is not set, then the output format is inferred from the
> extension of fname, if any, and from rcParams["savefig.format"] =
> 'png' otherwise. If format is set, it determines the output format.

And also :

> format : str The file format, e.g. 'png', 'pdf', 'svg', ... The
> behavior when this is unset is documented under fname.

:)

Answer (score 0):

try to use the str `replace` method.

```py
>>> "Hello World".replace("World", "Anatoli")
'Hello Anatoli'
```

in your case :

```py
plt.savefig(filename.replace(".py", ".pdf")
```

This will take the name of your file, but will remove `.py` and write `.pdf` instead, which is what you want.

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform.  You can also add a link to documentation, if that helps.